# How to do unit test for repository using xunit?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I'm using vs2017, framework target is .net core 1.1

My project structure:

```
Solution
       | 
       |-- WebAPI   
       |-- UnitTest    
       |-- IRepository
       |-- Repository
       |-- Model
```

What if I want to have unit test of repository, to test methods such as `insert` `remove` etc.. execute expectantly. How should I code?

My trail:
Dependencies added (IRepository, Repository, Model projects also added)

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Library structure:

```
UnitTest Library
           | 
           |-- UnitTest1.cs 

public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly ISeqRepository _Repo;

    public UnitTest1(ISeqRepository Repo)
    {
        _Repo = Repo;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Assert.Equal(_Repo.Insert(null), -1);
    }
}
```

Failed message after test:

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture
>   data: ISeqRepository repo

(There is no Startup.cs, how can I inject repository?)

Comment: You can't. It's called unit test, not integration test. Xunit doesn't support inject, except via Class Fixtures which is not really DI but to reuse a state

Comment: How about mocking repository and checking what parameters it was called with? And have separate set of unit tests for the repository itself?

Comment: How's self-test of repository? Is there any tutorial?